# Can this loop be written more succinctly?

Tags: c#

I have two [queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), let's say A and B, on which I execute the following algorithm:

```
while (queueA.Count > 0)
{
    var elemA = queueA.Peek();
    var elemB = queueB.Peek();
    if (AreSimilar(elemA, elemB))
    {
        Debug.Assert(elemA.SomeProperty == elemB.SomeProperty);
        queueA.Dequeue();
        queueB.Dequeue();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }    
}
```

Something tells me this could be written more succinctly; Peek() and Dequeue() might be combined in one operation as Dequeue() returns the same element as Peek(), and the if statement might be fused with the while statement, avoiding an explicit break. I'm just not seeing how to preserve the same behavior exactly, i.e. I don't want to remove an element unless it satisfies the condition in the 'if'.

Comment: I don't think `Peek` and `Dequeue` can be combined, since they execute under different conditions.

Comment: You can simplify a bit by doing `if (AreSimilar(queueA.Peek(), queueB.Peek())) {` but then you lose your ability to do your assert.

Comment: Sounds like [Micro-Optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html) and the real answer is, unless you are actually having performance issues, this is a waste of time, especially when it would be hard to tell how the compiler optimizes it.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm not worried about performance, just that I might be missing the obvious.

Comment: Ahh sounds like something for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code that moves the assignment into the invocation of `AreSimilar`:

```
QueueElement elemA, elemB
while (queueA.Count > 0 && AreSimilar(elemA = queueA.Peek(), elemB = queueB.Peek())) {
    Debug.Assert(elemA.SomeProperty == elemB.SomeProperty);
    queueA.Dequeue();
    queueB.Dequeue();
}
```

Note that this is not necessarily more readable. In fact, your version is pretty good in terms of readability. The only thing I would do is inverting the condition to decrease nesting, but I'd leave everything else in place:

```
while (queueA.Count > 0)
{
    var elemA = queueA.Peek();
    var elemB = queueB.Peek();
    if (!AreSimilar(elemA, elemB))
    {
        break;
    }
    Debug.Assert(elemA.SomeProperty == elemB.SomeProperty);
    queueA.Dequeue();
    queueB.Dequeue();
}
```

Comment: ewww inline assignment?

Comment: Note that smaller code is not always more readable.  This code will not be any faster, and is significantly less readable than the original.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Well, 25+ years of coding in C tend to leave their mark on one's way of perceiving the beauty :) I fell in love with assignments embedded into conditions as soon as I realized what the semicolon was doing in the `while(*dest++ = *src++) ;` example in the K&R.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Clever code is not always readable. Someone reading your example snippet will have to ask themselves if you really meant `=`, or if that is incorrect and `==` was the intended operator. Trying to figure out what you meant is not where readers should be spending their time.

Comment: @cdhowie Well, the OP did ask for a more succinct code, that's why I wrote something bordering on C code, but in C#. I edited the answer to include a more readable alternative (not surprisingly, it's almost an exact copy of the OP's code, improved slightly to reduce nesting).

Comment: Indeed, I'm just pointing out that "more succinct" does not imply "better."  The OP should be made aware of this, as your edited answer states.

Answer (score 2):

What is the likelyhood that A and B would be similar? If the probability is high, you could always run w/ the assumed common scenario and Pop them (or Dequeue) them ASSUMING they'll be similar and then just worry about pushing them back on if they aren't similar...

Comment: That doesn't necessarily make the code more readable though, it just inverts the condition and actually makes it less readable (since there is no documented method on Queue to insert an object at the *front* of the queue, and one would have to resort to reflection to get at the object's internals).

Comment: I didn't take readability and succinctness to necessarily mean the same thing... Dr_Asik also didn't say that items going onto the end of the queue was not an option... I agree that it could be considerably slower if the majority of the time it's having to repush the stuff back on the queue... It seemed like such an ethereal question that I just attempted to challenge some assumptions

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the loop with the help of a method, but you might consider this cheating:

```
static bool DequeuePairIf<T>(
    Func<T, T, bool> predicate,
    Queue<T> queueA,
    Queue<T> queueB)
{
    if (queueA.Count != 0 &&
        queueB.Count != 0 &&
        predicate(queueA.Peek(), queueB.Peek())
    ) {
        queueA.Dequeue();
        queueB.Dequeue();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then your loop becomes:

```
while (DequeuePairIf(AreSimilar, queueA, queueB)) { }
```

But I question if this kind of refactoring will help readability, or harm it.  It's considerably larger than the original code, for one thing.  On the other hand, smaller code is not always more readable.

(I removed the assert to simplify the logic here.  If you still need to assert, then you will have to save the results of the `Peek()` invocations, as you do in your original code.)